# Concat in not working inside case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, case

I have a month column with values from 1,2,3 up to 12. I am writing below query to convert column values with 1 digit to 2 digits that is values like 1 and 2 will be converted to 01 and 02, but that concatenation is not working, the month still remains as single digit.

Main query:

```
select 
    case 
        when len(month) = 1 
            then concat(0, month) 
            else month 
    end as month_new,
    month
from
    Table
```

But when I tried the query separately as below the concatenation works and it converts single digit month to 2 digits

Query 1

```
select top 10 concat(0, month), month
from table
```

Query 1 alone is working

Query 2

```
select 
    case 
        when len(month) = 1 
            then 1 
            else 0 
    end, 
    month
from
    Table
```

Query 2 alone is working, means the checking of length in column month is working as expected. But when concat used inside case it is not working.

I have modified the query as below and worked for me

```
select 
    case 
        when len(month) = 1 
            then concat(0, month) 
            else cast(month as varchar)
    end as month_new,
    month
from
    table
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results and explain what "not working" means.

Comment: You seems to mixing up your string and integer. The problem is your `case` expression. Please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the `Return Types` section of the `CASE` expression. Also [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `month` is an integer, whereas the result from `concat()` is a string. So. `case` is trying to cast the string back into an integer. You could force the integer into a string by using `cast`, but there are better ways to do this.

Instead, just use the `FORMAT` function:

```sql
select
     format(month, '00') as month_new
   , month
from viivscaazure.F_SALES_DETAIL
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know what database are you using and since you don't provide any sample data I only can assume that your `CASE` is not the problem, but if you want to do so that means your datatype is string and you tried to `CONCAT` string with integer in your query.

Maybe you can try to add "quote" to your zero string and `CAST` the result as a string.